# collections.sort not sorting, get output unsorted only

Tags: java, arrays, collections, compareto

My Java program is not sorting the outputs. I am not experienced with Java and after looking through similar questions I wasn't able to figure out the issue with my code.

The output shows the 3 spheres and their colors but does not display the radius or sort them by their area like it should.

Below are the 3 .java files involved in my program, I have no errors or warnings in Eclipse so I am assuming I have put some parameter or value in the wrong place... I appreciate any help thanks so much!

ComparableSphere.java

```
public class ComparableSphere extends GeometricObject implements Comparable<ComparableSphere>{

private double radius;

public ComparableSphere(){
    this("white",0);
    this.radius = 0;
}
public ComparableSphere(String color, double radius){
    super(color);
    this.radius = radius;
}
public double area() {
    return Math.PI * this.radius * this.radius * 4;
}
public double perimeter() {
    return 2 * Math.PI * this.radius;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(ComparableSphere o) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
```

}

GeometricObject.java

```
public abstract class GeometricObject {

private String color;


protected GeometricObject(){
    this("white");
}


protected GeometricObject(String color) {
    this.color = color;
}


public String getColor(){
    return this.color;
}


public void setColor(String color){
    this.color = color;
}


public abstract double area();


public abstract double perimeter();


public String toString() {
    return this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ": color= " + this.color;
}



public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(!(obj instanceof GeometricObject)){
        return false;
    }

    GeometricObject other = (GeometricObject)obj;
    return this.color.equalsIgnoreCase(other.color);
}
```

}

driver.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class driver {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ComparableSphere sphere1 = new ComparableSphere("Purple", 10.1);
        ComparableSphere sphere2 = new ComparableSphere("Orange", 3.8);
        ComparableSphere sphere3 = new ComparableSphere("Tan", 5.2);

        ArrayList<ComparableSphere> sphereList = new ArrayList<ComparableSphere>();

        sphereList.add(sphere1);
        sphereList.add(sphere2);
        sphereList.add(sphere3);

        System.out.println("Unsorted list: \n"+sphereList+"\n");

        Collections.sort(sphereList);
        System.out.println("Sorted list: \n"+sphereList);

}
```

}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNgyy.png)

Comment: You don't seem to have written a `compareTo` method.  How are you expecting your objects to be sorted, when your program has no way of comparing two objects?

Comment: `public int compareTo(ComparableSphere o) { return 0; }` means that all objects are compared *equal* (since that is what return value 0 means), and if they are all equal, why would you expect `sort()` to do anything at all? --- **Implement the `compareTo` method.**

Comment: Write it where? The compareTo method is in ComparableSphere.java, does it also need to be somewhere in driver.java?

Answer (score 0):

Your `compareTo` always returns `0`, so that means that you are considering all `ComparableSphere` objects equal to each other, according to [the `compareTo` contract](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)):

> Compares this object with the specified object for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

This means that `Collections.sort` thinks it has nothing to do, because all the objects are equal to each other.

You need to write the logic in the `compareTo` method to make the comparison between this object and the passed-in object and return an appropriate value.  This will give `Collections.sort` the information it needs to sort the list properly.

Comment: I see what I did wrong here. I tried to add:

`return this.radius.compareTo(o.radius);`

but I am now getting an error Cannot invoke compareTo(double) on the primitive type double

Comment: After looking around I see that I can't use compareTo on the double type. Do I need to re-write my code to use compareTo or is there some other way to implement compareTo with the code I have?

Comment: Use [`Double.compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compare(double,double)).